# How to get Parse User information from User object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is there a direct way to get Parse User information like name, password etc from object Pointer<_User>? Right now I have to do another query on User to match objectId with 'id' in object Pointer<_User> to get  those info. Is there a quicker way to do that since the object is of type Pointer<_User>, and in Parse data, you can click on that, which would directly link to that User object (see screenshot).
[image]

Comment: `query.include('userid')`